# Phantom songs on Cyanogenmod 10.1 phone

Tags: cyanogenmod, music

I am running Cyanogenmod 10.1 nightly (2013-02-19) on my Samsung Galaxy SII (I9100), and have about 190 songs on it that I listen to with the latest Songbird app.

The strange thing is Songbird thinks there are 380 songs (i.e. two times 190) and shows me a duplicate of each song I have on the phone. For each song, one copy plays fine, and the other copy doesn't play and doesn't show its cover art.

I tried clearing the Songbird data and cache but that didn't help. I also tried to install the JUST PLAYER music app and it showed the same problem!

Does anyone have thoughts as to where these duplicate phantom songs are coming from? Is there some data store or cache in the Android system that I could clear or reset to resolve this issue?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem on your ROM. I also had that issue, until the ROM dev fixed the sdcard mount points. It is because your sdcard has two symlinks (usually @ /mnt/sdcard and /storage or whatever) so your phone thinks that you have 2 sdcards. You can solve this by excluding one of the mounts like I do on MXPlayer before it was fixed. You should inform your ROM dev about this issue so he can fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Is there a way to exclude that either in Songbird or another music player? Thanks.

Comment: I dont know, I am not a fan of music and I mostly use my phone for movies, anime and games :D try to ask others